# Can I use sql recursive in sql cursor?

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I'm writing a procedure which want to excecute the function recursively in  cursor by using mssql.

The function `ParseJson` in the following code is refer to  [How to parse JSON string recursively with openjson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704149/how-to-parse-json-string-recursively-with-openjson)

PS. Reference example is recursive version, but in my question it is parse step by step.

It's the first result of my function `ParseJson`

```
    topKey     Key         isTerminal     Value
    Book       IssueDate   1              02-15-2019
    Book       Detail      0              { "Type":"Any Type", "Author":{ "Name":"Annie" , "Sex":"Female"}
    Book       Chapter     0              [{ "Section":"1.1", "Title":"Hello world." }, { "Section":"1.2", "Title":"Be happy." }]
    Book       Sponsor     0              ["A","B","C"]
```

The value of each column `isTerminal` is the condition, 
when `isTerminal=0` then execute the function `ParseJson`;
when `isTerminal=1` then print something.

I'm create a procedure to excecute the function recursively in sql cursor.
The function is create sucessful, but excecute fail.

```
create procedure CursorJson
    @json nvarchar(max)
    , @Type nvarchar(max) 
    , @isArray bit = 0
as
begin

    set nocount on

    declare 
        @TopKey nvarchar(4000)
        , @Key nvarchar(4000)
        , @IsType bit
        , @IsList bit
        , @isTerminal bit
        , @Value nvarchar(4000)

    --defind
    declare myCursor cursor for

    --dataset
    select * from ParseJson(@json, @Type, @isArray) 

    --open
    open myCursor

    --run
    fetch next from myCursor into 
            @TopKey nvarchar(4000)
            , @Key nvarchar(4000)
            , @IsType bit
            , @IsList bit
            , @isTerminal bit
            , @Value nvarchar(4000)

    while(@@fetch_status = 0)
    begin
        if @isTerminal = 0 
        begin
            set @json = '{"' + @Key + '":' + @Value + '}'
            exec CursorJson @json, @Key, @isList 
        end
        else
        begin
            print 'insert...'
        end

        fetch next from myCursor into 
                @TopKey nvarchar(4000)
                , @Key nvarchar(4000)
                , @IsType bit
                , @IsList bit
                , @isTerminal bit
                , @Value nvarchar(4000)
    end

    --close and deallocate
    close myCursor 
    deallocate myCursor

    return
end
```

```
declare @Type nvarchar(max)=N'Book'
declare 
    @json nvarchar(max)=N'{
    "Book":{
        "IssueDate":"02-15-2019"
        , "Detail":{
            "Type":"Any Type"
            , "Author":{
                "Name":"Annie"
                , "Sex":"Female"
            }
        }
        , "Chapter":[
            {
                "Section":"1.1"
                , "Title":"Hello world."
            }
            ,
            {
                "Section":"1.2"
                , "Title":"Be happy."
            }       
        ]
        , "Sponsor":["A","B","C"]
    }
}'  

--exec
exec CursorJson @json, @Type, 0
```

> Program CursorJson, [Batch Start Line 0] The cursor with the name 'myCursor' already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "quick fix" would be to specify that the [cursor is local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
declare myCursor cursor local for
```

But I'd seriously re-examine whether you can achieve what you're trying to do by using a [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead.